# how can I copy some characters into string in c++

Tags: c++, string, copy, character

In one part of my code I should get characters one by one. It's easy but my question is how can I add these characters one by one into a string. Note that I don't know how many characters I will get.
It is important that just the characters be copied in string. In the other words, I want to generate words from characters until the character is not equal to `' '` or `'\n'` .
the wrong code that I wrote is:

```
 char c;
 string str = NULL;
 cin.get(c);
 while (c != " ")
 {
      str += c;
      cin.get(c);
 }
 cout << str ;
```

For example, if character `c` would be `'H'` at first and then be `'i'`,
I want to the string str  to be `"Hi"` on `cout`!

Comment: Why `string str = NULL;` and not simply `string str;`? This isn't `char*`

Comment: ok I changed it but the code is wrong too.

Comment: @0bijanmortazavi Please don't accept an answer until you're certain it fits your needs and then I'd encourage you not to change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=!` should be `!=`, and the string `" "` should be a character `' '`.

If you want to check for new-line characters as well as space:

```
while (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
```

or perhaps

```
while (!std::isspace(c))
```

which will read up to any whitespace character.

You should also check for the end of the stream or other problems:

```
while (cin.get(c) && !std::isspace(c)) {
    str += c;
}
```

Comment: `str += c` will do that.

Comment: no it's wrong I have a lots of c characters and the lenght of str is not given

Comment: It's in a loop, so it will append a different character (the one you just read from `cin`) to the string each time. You'll end up with all the input characters (until the first space) in the string, like you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read until a space or newline:

```
std::getline( cin, str, ' ' );
```

Comment: Nope. `std::getline` stops either at the default delimiting character (\n) or the one that you provide, not both. For instance, consider this code and input: http://ideone.com/rMLH5G

The result is expected to be just "Foo"

Answer (score 1):

c++ [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) are also useful when building strings

```
stringstream ss;
while (cin.get(c) && !std::isspace(c)) {
    ss << c;
}
string s = ss.str();
cout << s;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in your code was that you weren't checking for the newline character.
Also, it should have been `!=` instead of `=!`. The second option will actually behave as `c = (!(" "))` in your code. Another mistake is that you should be checking for the blank space character `' '` instead of an empty string `" "`.

Here is the correct code:

```
char c;
string str = "";
while (true)
{
     cin.get(c);
     cout << "c is " << c << endl;       
         if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\n'))
     break;
     str += c;
}
cout << str << endl ;
```

Also, if your requirement is that the I/O be stopped the moment a space character is encountered, refer to this question: [C - Reading from stdin as characters are typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004895/c-reading-from-stdin-as-characters-are-typed)

All the solutions proposed here will continue to read input until the new line character is entered because until then your input hasn't been processed, but instead stored in a buffer.

Comment: Obijan mortazavi : Sorry, I had done some stupid mistake in my code. I know its unacceptable, but in my defense its 4 am here. Anyway, this code should solve the problem. However, you still need to press enter as the I/O does not stop after a blank space. But the final returned answer just contains data till the first blank space.

Comment: the problem is not while !!!! is how can I copy or add characters one by in a string?

Comment: Obijan mortazavi : the str += c adds a character to the end of string str. In other words, str += c is the same as str = str + c. The get in the loop will keep reading characters one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If your `str` starts out empty, this is simple:

```
string str;

cin >> str; // cin's >> operator already reads until whitespace

cout << str;
```

Comment: I have to give characters one by one using char variable! ok?

Comment: @0bijanmortazavi I'm not certain why you'd want to do it this way but if that's what you want then [Mike Seymour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour)'s answer is a good one.

Comment: how can i copy or add characters into string? this is my problem now. please help me

Comment: @0bijanmortazavi If you are willing to type the whole line at the prompt and then press enter my code will use `cin`'s `operator>>` to put the first word in `str`. If you need to read in character by character, [Mike Seymour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour)'s use of `string`'s `operator+=` will do the copy.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know in advance how many characters it would be, I would declare a std::list, push elements to it and then copy them into a string. This ensures that you don't reallocate the string memory on every addition:

```
char c;
list<char> buff;
cin.get(c);
while (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
{
    buff.push_back (c);
    cin.get(c);
}
string str (buff.size(), 0);
size_t i = 0;
while (!buff.empty())
{
    str[i] = buff.front();
    buff.pop_front();
    ++i;
}
cout << str ;
```

Comment: the line "std::list<char> buff;" has an error may be it is for the library. please help me

Comment: What kind of error? Did you `#include <list>` in the header?

Comment: thank you very much but it has a new error for this line "std::string str (buff.size());" I think this is for size type

Comment: Right, there was an error in the string declaration. I'll fix it.

Comment: please give me a code to copy or add characters one by one into string

Comment: Fixed. The code is now compiling and running as expected: http://ideone.com/Qcnx5W