# C safe and proper way to get user input

Tags: c, validation, input

Safe input is harder than I thought. I looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831755/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-getting-user-input-in-c), but it is from 2011 and things might have changed since then.

I'm looking for something that can handle string input and single character input. For example:

```
Hello, what's your name?
My name is: _
```

```
Are you sure?
[Y] Yes, hello
[N] No, goodbye
_
```

Here is the way I'm doing it right now:

```c
char input[16];
fgets(input, 16, stdin);
```

```c
char input = getchar();
```

My problem has always been that the user may input arbitrarily long input or invalid input. How can I read input safely and ensure future inputs won't get borked?

Looking for solutions that work in C and across Linux / Windows.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *... Afterwards, flush stdin so ...* – Don't ever think if you can `fflush(stdin)`. It would invoke UB.

Comment: In C its very easy to make a dynamic string. in C++ you can use `std:string foo; std::cin >> foo`. If you want, I can write the C version as an answer?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate Wait with that until OP has made up their mind about what language this question is about.

Comment: You might be interested in reading: [Reading from stdin as characters are typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004895/c-reading-from-stdin-as-characters-are-typed) and [Capture characters from standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: You can also use `termios.h` to go into raw mode but that's Unix-specific

Comment: @klutt How about I just provide both?

Comment: @klutt Apologies, I narrowed the language I'm looking for.

Comment: @404NameNotFound So should I post the way to read infinite input safely in C?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate IMO, it's then better if you write a self answered question for C++, now when OP has narrowed it down to C

Comment: @RohanBari Yes I know I can't flush `stdin` that way, my intention is so that future inputs don't get borked. A common experience for me is forgetting that a newline character still exists in the input buffer, borking up next reads.

Comment: You might want to have a look here OP https://stackoverflow.com/q/58403537/6699433

Comment: Yeah I have a solution for C using malloc, realloc and getchar

Comment: @404NameNotFound I wrote an answer to the question I linked. The main thing is "Read data with fgets and process it with sscanf. Never read with scanf."

Comment: You should never write `char input = getchar()`, because `getchar` returns an int.  You must store it in an `int` so that you can check against EOF.

Comment: @ImportAccelerate Could you please also do a C++ one? I'm also intersted in that.

Comment: C++ version is just `std::string input; std::cin >> input;` full stop. Also, if you think my answer is correct, you can press the Checkmark button next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to read infinite standard input safely. You can just use a continuously reallocating buffer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_line(size_t* length) {
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t cap = 4;
    char* buffer = malloc(cap);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Virtual memory exhausted\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char current;
    while ((current = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (len + 1 > cap) {
            cap *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, cap);
        }
        buffer[len++] = current;
    }
    // One last time for NUL terminator
    if (len + 1 > cap) {
        cap *= 2;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, cap);
    }        
    buffer[len] = 0;

    if (length) *length = len;
    return buffer;
}
```

This function will read `stdin` char-by-char and add it to a string which is returned. Optionally you can ask for its length. Don't forget to `free`.

```c
int main() {
    char* line = get_line(NULL);
    printf("You entered: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
}
```

NOTE: This code is meant to be of little verbosity so some checks were omitted. In production code checking `realloc` and using `int` for `getchar()` to test for EOF is necessary.

Comment: You did not check return value of `realloc`

Comment: That is true. I will add a note that this is meant to be of little verbosity and that in production code checking `realloc` is necessary.

Comment: If I may ask, what is the parameter `size_t* length` for here? Is it for "Optionally you can ask for its length"? Also, does reading character by character not incur overhead? I don't have any statistics to verify, but I feel like reading by character would be less efficient than directly reading a chunk. Or is it negligible?

Comment: There's not much overhead here since most terminals are line-buffered so all the characters are already available. `size_t* length` is an optional parameter, pass a pointer to a `size_t` and it will store the string length there to avoid a subsequent `strlen`. Otherwise just pass `NULL`.